# How to convert a raw query to a stander query method of SQLiteDatabase?

Tags: android, database

I have such a raw query statement

```
String selectQuery_all_books = "SELECT " + TABLE_BOOKS + "." + KEY_TITLE_ID + " As _id, "
                    + KEY_TITLE + ", " + KEY_PRICE + ", " + KEY_ISBN
                    +", GROUP_CONCAT(" + KEY_AUTHOR + ", ', ') AS authors"
                    + " FROM " + TABLE_BOOKS + " JOIN " + TABLE_AUTHORS
                    + " USING (" + KEY_TITLE_ID + ")"
                    + " GROUP BY " + KEY_TITLE_ID;
```

Now, I want use SQLiteDatabase method [query](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query(java.lang.String,java.lang.String[],java.lang.String,java.lang.String[],java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) to rewrite it to get same style cursor. Is that possible?